# Remove element style of loader magento backend

Tags: jquery, css, magento

I am customizing loader of magento backend. I have successfully overwritten the html of loader keeping the id (loading-mask) same and it is working totally fine except for some places for ex. clicking on "Save and Continue Edit" on "Manage products" page. There it is adding some extra element style to loading-mask id like :

```
left: -2px; top: 48px; width: 1349px; height: 1620px;
```

But I do not want these extra css as it is not good for my custom loader. So where I can change the code (wherever in magento core js files) so that it do not add these extra element style to loading-mask ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding

```
#loading-mask{height: auto!important;left: 0!important;top: 0!important;width: auto!important;}
```

in css.